# Relative Path in Maven parent definition

Tags: maven

In defining a parent artifact, do I need to include the  in the child's pom? For example,

Is the `<relativePath>` optional or required?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tutorials</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is not required. From [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent):

> `relativePath`: The relative path of the parent `pom.xml` file within the check out. If not specified, it defaults to `../pom.xml`. [...]

This means that you can omit this element and it will default to exactly what you already have, i.e. Maven will look for the parent POM in `../pom.xml` which is one directory up.

Answer (score 0):

according to the maven [doc](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#inheritance) :

```
Notice the relativePath element. It is not required, but may be used as a signifier to Maven to first search the path given for this project's parent, before searching the local and then remote repositories.
```