# How to access POM file directory inside POM file using ${}

Tags: maven-3, java-11

I have a JDK11 Maven parent project and a POM file in C:\workspaces\parent-project\pom.xml
This is the POM file I run with "mvn clean install".
I also have other children projects.
Inside this parent POM I need to access the directory in which it resides.

I have this plugin in the parent POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
    <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <configFile>${project.basedir}/java-formatter-configuration.xml</configFile>
     <overrideConfigCompilerVersion>true</overrideConfigCompilerVersion>
     <compilerSource>11</compilerSource>
     <compilerCompliance>11</compilerCompliance>
     <compilerTargetPlatform>11</compilerTargetPlatform>
     <lineEnding>CRLF</lineEnding>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>        
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>format</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately ${project.basedir} returns the directory of the children projects as they build 1-by-1. Tomcat has the variable ${CATALINA_BASE} that points at the installation directory of Tomcat. Is there the same I can do in the parent POM so that I can represent the directory in which the parent POM resides? Meaning, do you know which Maven variable I can use to access the directory
C:\workspaces\parent-project?
I had to make a copy of this formatter XML in every single project. I just want to have one formatter XML in the parent folder.
Thank you

Comment: If Maven uses the installed version of your parent project then there is no directory. Installed artifacts are stored in in your home directory `.m2/repository/...` in JAR form. If you want to use the project directory use the `<relativePath>` and specify the relative path to the parent project in each child project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608981/relative-path-in-maven-parent-definition

Comment: Thank you Robert. I updated the question with more info, but I will try to understand how to use <relativePath> if there is no easier solution

Comment: May be you should write why you think you need file-system access to the parent project so the community can help you to find a different way that don't need access parent project directly.

Comment: Because I have 86 projects and I had ot copy/pste the same java-formatter-configuration.xml (used by the Maven plugin) and it doesn't seem like a good idea. I would prefer to have this XML file in one location i.e. in the parent project's directory so that when each <module>'s POM executes, the plugin can get the path of the XML file. All in one place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to read the documentation of the [formatter-maven-plugin](https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/examples.html#Multimodule_Configuration) because it support a configuration setup where you don't need file system access out of the box.

Comment: thank you very much khmarbaise. Now the formatter.xml is in one place only and not 86. It works!